Who are the powers in Hoist the colours lyrics
The lyrics of Hoist the colours by Hans Zimmer starts like this:
The King and his men
stole the Queen from her bed
and bound her in her bones
the seas be ours and by the powers
where we will we'll roam

AFAIU this divides in the following phrases:
The King and his men stole the Queen from her bed and bound her in her bones
and
the seas be ours and by the powers
where we will we'll roam
This last phrase is what I'm not understanding very well. Again AFAIU it's divided in 2 parts
the seas be ours
and
by the powers where we will we'll roam
Is that it? So my questions are:
By which powers? The powers that are where they will? Huh? By the powers that are where they roam they will roam? ??
Can someone explain that last phrase? Thanks

You will find transcriptions that include a comma, which may aid in understanding that will means want here:

the seas be ours and by the powers where we will, we’ll roam


will verb1
I.i.1.a. Expressing desire: to wish for, have a mind to, want (something); to desire (a person, gold, etc.). Sometimes also with the
implication of intention or purpose. In later use frequently with
what alone or as head of a clause.
I.i.1.a.i. transitive. In present tense. Obsolete. Old English–1862 [selected attestation] 1735
   You do not make your greatness consist in being able to do
whatever you will, but in willing only what may be done. —translation
of C. Rollin, Ancient History vol. III. 65 Source:
Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

This now-obsolete usage of will fits in with the pirates’ timeline.
In pirate-speak, by the Powers, means swearing by something, usually God (see under by Thunder).
You can read the whole thing like this:

The seas be ours and, by God, we’ll roam where we want.


Perfect explanation. Thanks.

I think "where we will we'll roam" just means "we'll roam where we will", that is, we'll go wherever we want.
As to "by the powers", it may be a shorter way of saying "the powers that be", as described here
Wikipedia "the powers that be"

I read the meaning of "powers" a little differently - more explicitly supernatural (as in divine or diabolical) - and chosen as a rhyme to "ours".
